# <li> items appearing in same line in Mobile version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this issue when the viewport switches to a mobile version
using bootstrap v3

when the navbar switches to the mobile version of itself , the 2nd and the 3rd element come on the same line , because they have a dropdown class under them.
as shown in the picture. [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qDA.png) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzjlu.png)

if the drowpdown class isnt put then the elements show themselves properly 
any help here?

```
<div class="navbar-header ">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="Deccan Airsports Logo">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="scroll">
      <a href="index.html#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll dropdown">
      <a href="index.html#services1" class="dropbtn">Hot Air Balloon <span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-xs"> </span></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content hidden-sm hidden-xs">

        <a href="book-a-ride.html">Book A Ride</a>
        <a href="membership.html">Membership</a>
        <a href="faq.html">FAQs</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll dropdown">
      <a href="index.html#portfolio" class="dropbtn">Services<span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <a href="gliders.html">Gliders</a>
        <a href="sky-diving.html">Sky-Diving</a>
        <a href="drones.html">Drones</a>
        <a href="hang-gliders.html">Hang-Gliders</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
    <li class="scroll dropdown"><a href="events.html" class="dropbtn">Events<span class="caret "></a></span>
      <div class="dropdown-content hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <a href="uc.html">News & Press</a>
        <a href="uc.html">Branding</a>
        <a href="uc.html">Advertisement</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: This appears to be a CSS issue and you've shown no CSS.

Comment: yes, it was a CSS issue. The Dropdown class had a display:inline-block. @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be with your "dropdown" class - make sure it doesn't have display:inline.